# Find phrases in a single document

Tags: ruby, search

I have a web app that allows users to upload text documents (of about 2-3000 words), and a database table with about 50,000 phrases (as strings).

How can I most efficiently find out which phrases appear in each of those uploaded documents? (i.e. is there anything better than brute-forcing it by checking each phrase separately?)

The web app flow should ideally be that on the page load after upload, the app knows which phrases it has found in that one document.

Ideally I'd like a solution in ruby, but suggestions as to other technologies or data structures or anything would be a real help.

Comment: Do you have to check this more than once?

Comment: It seems to me that, conceptually, you have no way other than checking each phrase separately. You may use some optimization tricks, though (indexes and whatnot) to make individual checks faster.

Comment: @Stefan's question is the most pertinent. If you only have to do it once, brute-force it and call it a day. Barring that, another pertinent question is: How big is your document? For a small document (say, Shakespeare's *Comedy of Errors*) the best approach may be different from a large document (e.g. the complete works of Shakespeare).

Comment: For what it's worth, here's a pretty good article on a common approach to this kind of problem: https://www.toptal.com/algorithms/needle-in-a-haystack-a-nifty-large-scale-text-search-algorithm

Comment: @Stefan it is once each for multiple documents. I am creating a web app where people can upload the documents, and then we need to find out if the document has any of the phrases. I don't expect each document to be more than 2-3000 words.

Comment: @DanSingerman I think you should clarify that in your question. _"I have a single text document"_ sounds a bit misleading ;-)

Comment: @stefan have updated as you advised. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the database you are using, so I just give a MySQL solution:

```
require 'mysql2'

content = File.read('/path/to/document.txt')

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")

sql = "SELECT phrase FROM phrases ORDER BY LENGTH(phrase)"

appeared = client.query(sql, as: :array, stream: true).each.with_object([]) do |row, array|
  array << row[0] if content.gsub!(%r[#Regexp.escape(row[0])]i, '')
end
```

The idea is to shrink the content after each match so that next search will be faster.

DISCLAIMER: Not tested.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks. I just changed it to `String#gsub!`